# The name 'Assets' does not exist in the current context

Tags: android, xamarin.android, assets

I have a problem with this line of code. Want to create sqlite database on the device.

```
 string dbPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) + "\\test.db";
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(dbPath))

            using (System.IO.Stream sr = ***Assets***.Open("test.db"))
            {
                using (System.IO.Stream srTo = System.IO.File.Create(dbPath))
                {
                    sr.CopyTo(srTo);
                }
            }
```

This message gives the:
    The name 'Assets' does not exist in the current context

have a similar project, but more comprehensive than big. There is no error. They Assets Where I'm following definition defines a cs file in c drive gives reference to Android.Content.ContextWrapper.
is not on The project the path.
[How the file was added application?

Comment: Where in your code is this? Is this in an activity?

Comment: Yes it is inside Activity

Answer (score 3):

If you aren't doing this in an activity you need a reference to the Activity/Context. You will need to pass this in to your helper class in the constructor.

```
public yourClass(Activity context.......){

      context.Assets.Open("your.db");
}
```

Comment: Mercy. You've done the changes but it is still the same problem.

Comment: I just ran an example on my machine. Assets should be there as long as you hold the activity ref. It should compile. The Assets is a C# property for the AssetManager which only works with an Activity its not a global.

Comment: have a similar project, but more comprehensive than big. There is no error. They Assets Where I'm following definition defines a cs file in c drive gives reference to Android.Content.ContextWrapper. is not on The project the path. [How the file was added application?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
using (System.IO.Stream sr = Android.App.Application.Context.Assets.Open("test.db"))
{
     using (System.IO.Stream srTo = System.IO.File.Create(dbPath))
     {
          sr.CopyTo(srTo);
     }
}
```